# Proper term 劝合不劝散

Tags: mandarin, terminology

Came across this, old(?), term today:
`劝合不劝散`.

A quick *baidu* gives me a lot of variants on this term though:

劝合不劝离

劝合不劝分

And

劝和不劝散

劝和不劝分

劝和不劝离

I would imagine anything with 和 would be a more widely accepted variant, than those with 合.

But is there a most widely accepted term among the whole 散、分、离 group?

Comment: Vote for `劝合不劝离`.

Comment: 和 means peace .以和为贵

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick googling gives:

+"劝合不劝散" -"劝合不劝离" -"劝合不劝分" -"劝和不劝散" -"劝和不劝分" -"劝和不劝离" = 698

-"劝合不劝散" +"劝合不劝离" -"劝合不劝分" -"劝和不劝散" -"劝和不劝分" -"劝和不劝离" = 11500

-"劝合不劝散" -"劝合不劝离" +"劝合不劝分" -"劝和不劝散" -"劝和不劝分" -"劝和不劝离" = 10700

-"劝合不劝散" -"劝合不劝离" -"劝合不劝分" +"劝和不劝散" -"劝和不劝分" -"劝和不劝离" = 3160

-"劝合不劝散" -"劝合不劝离" -"劝合不劝分" -"劝和不劝散" +"劝和不劝分" -"劝和不劝离" = 25200

-"劝合不劝散" -"劝合不劝离" -"劝合不劝分" -"劝和不劝散" -"劝和不劝分" +"劝和不劝离" = 32500

Comment: Care to explain a little I have no idea what any of that means....

Comment: In Google, quoting "...." means exact match, "+" means "must exist" and "-" means "must not exist".

Comment: @user3306356 It simply says Google indexed "劝和不劝离" the most while "劝合不劝散" least. It may not fully explain the term (I did not hear this before either) but sure gives a picture on how people on the Internet use these terms.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to say,`劝合不劝散` ，`劝合不劝分` and `劝合不劝离` almost the same meaning.

```
 And 合 is the opposite meaning of 离 and 散 .
```

> Like a couples, we prefer they live together instead of 散 or 离

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. I know they all have the same meaning, hence the word `variants` in the question. The meaning is, likewise, quite clear. The question is: is there an official, widely accepted one of the lot?

Answer (score 0):

In these terms, I think 分 and 离 is more acceptable than 散. 
 **分** usually used as a couple(not married) break up, **离** means a married couple divorced. 
 while **散** is much less used in my experience.